# setTimeout and jquery load

Tags: jquery, settimeout

How do I make `setTimeout` function here:

```
function loadContent(url){
    jQuery(".post").fadeTo(200,0.5);
        jQuery("#container").load(href + ' .posts', function(responseHtml){
            var newTitle = jQuery(responseHtml).filter('title').text();
            document.title = newTitle;
    });
}
```

I tried something like this but it does not work:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    jQuery("#container").load(href + ' .posts', function(responseHtml){
        var newTitle = jQuery(responseHtml).filter('title').text();
        document.title = newTitle;
    }); 
}, 1000);
```

I don't get any error.

Comment: what is `href`?? where is it defined?? and can you post errors from console..

Comment: href is defined above    href = jQuery(this).attr("href");
here is all code http://pastebin.com/53yN5Esj , and dont have any error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your function to.
Replace `href` in load to `url`

```
function loadContent(url){
    jQuery(".post").fadeTo(200,0.5);
    jQuery("#container").load(url+ ' .posts', function(responseHtml){
        var newTitle = jQuery(responseHtml).filter('title').text();
        document.title = newTitle;
    });
}
```

and if you want to call setTimeout in your loadCountent function you should do like

```
function loadContent(url){
    jQuery(".post").fadeTo(200,0.5);
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        jQuery("#container").load(url+ ' .posts', function(responseHtml){
            var newTitle = jQuery(responseHtml).filter('title').text();
            document.title = newTitle;
       });
   }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: @SheikhHeera, Yes, It is Loading Page Fragments.